# Minimal polynomial of $B^2$ when $B^3=B^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $B$ be an $N\times N$ matrix such that $B^3 =B^2$. Find the minimal polynomial of $B^2$.

I know that minimal polynomial of $B$ divides $x^3-x^2$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The zero matrix and the identity matrix both satisfy $B^3=B^2$, but their squares have different minimal polynomials. Hence, the question doesn't have a definite answer. Did you give us the complete question statement?

Comment: the question wants me to show that B^2 is diagonalisable given that B^3 -B^2=0.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete question statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From $B^3=B^2$ we obtain $B^4=B^3=B^2$. Therefore $x^2-x$ annihilates $B^2$ and the minimal polynomial of $B^2$ can only be $x,\,x-1$ or $x(x-1)$. Each of them is a possible choice. E.g. $x$ is the minimal polynomial of $0^2$, $x-1$ is the minimal polynomial of $I^2$ and $x(x-1)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\left(\operatorname{diag}(0,1)\right)^2$, and in each of these examples, we have $B^3=B^2$.

Comment: thank you. shouldn't the minimal polynomial be x(x-1) since the minimal polynomial of B^2 contains every eigenvalue?

Comment: my point is: let's say the characteristic polynomial is x^2-x then the minimal polynomial must be x(x-1).  Is this a true statement?

Comment: @User1825 The characteristic polynomial of $B^2$ has degree $N$. It cannot possibly be $x^2-x$ when $N\ne2$. Even if $N=2$, $x^2-x$ is not necessarily the characteristic polynomial of $B$. Consider $B=0$ for instance.